# Java append instances of a String to a String which separated by commas

Tags: java, string, variables, instance, delimiter

So I have a string variable which is meant to hold names of cars separated by commas.

```
String cars = "";
```

What I want to do is append cars to this string. The way a new car would be added:

```
String newCar1 = "Mini";
String newCar2 = "LandRover";
appendToCars(newCar1);
appendToCars(newCar2);
```

Then currently I have this, which I primarily need help with.

```
public void appendToCars(String newCar)
{
cars = cars + "," + newCar;
}
```

So output should be:

```
Mini,LandRover
```

but it's:

```
[,]Mini
```

Been racking my brain about this for hours figuring out how to do it, but I just can't get the result I actually want.

Im also using a JUnit test for this which reads :

```
@Test
public void testAppendToCars() {
    System.out.println("appendToCars");
    String newCar1 = "Mini";
    String newCar2 = "LandRover";
    String expResult = newCar1 + "," + newCar2;
    testDel.appendToCars(newCar1);
    testDel.appendToCars(newCar2);
    String result = testDel.getCars();
    assertEquals("Delivery notes incorrectly stored", expResult, result);
```

Comment: Your code seems find(except it should print `,Mini,LandRover`. Mind posting a full compilable example?

Comment: @IdanArye just edited my example forgot to mention im using a JUnit test

Comment: @bSky but what is testDel? Could you post your classes so we can see what exactly is going on?

Comment: @kolonel testDel is just a copy for testing of the constructors of the class with the appendToCars method so it can be appended to appendToCars within testDel. Hard to explain as ive just started using JUnit myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have a variable scope issue. This example uses your code but takes the scope into consideration:

```
public class temp {

    static String cars = "";

    public static void appendToCars(String something)
    {

        if (cars.equals("")){
            cars = something;
        }
        else {
            cars= cars + "," + something;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String newcar1 = "Mini";
        String newcar2 = "LandRover";

        appendToCars(newcar1);
        appendToCars(newcar2);
        System.out.println(cars);
    }
}
```

This class will return the following:

```
Mini,LandRover
```